# Problem with teckit_compile command

Tags: xetex

When I run following command in my Linux terminal:

```
teckit_compile itrans-dvn.map -o itrans-dvn.tec
```

Following notification appears:

> unable to open output file itrans-dvn.tec

What went wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining  what teckit_compile is. I never heard of it. Is it even related to latex and friends?

Comment: @daleif  usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-cygwin/teckit_compile (it's the unicode mapping processr used by xetex)  Do you have write access to  the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

by default texlive contains

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/xetex-itrans/
brh-kan.map      itrans-iast.tec    itrans-santel.map  itrans-tamil.tec
brh-kan.tec      itrans-kan.map     itrans-santel.tec  itrans-tel.map
itrans-dvn.map   itrans-kan.tec     itrans-sdvn.map    itrans-tel.tec
itrans-dvn.tec   itrans-sankan.map  itrans-sdvn.tec
itrans-iast.map  itrans-sankan.tec  itrans-tamil.map
```

so the compiled `.tec` files are already provided. If I copy `itrans-dvn.map` to a temporary directory where I have write access then

```
teckit_compile itrans-dvn.map -o itrans-dvn.tec
```

runs without error. You may or may not have write access in the install directory depending how texlive was installed (but it is probably a bad idea to update the files there "by hand" even if you do have write access/

Comment: Dear Sir, you where right, it was because of the write access. When I run the command with **sudo** it works. The reason why I asked you find in this thread: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380369/how-to-create-vedic-accents-anudatta-svarita-and-double-svarita-in-devanaga/380400#380400)