# Extending .map file with U+1CDA Vedic tone double svarita

Tags: indic

Two years ago I asked already a similar question, but couln't find a solution: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380369/how-to-create-vedic-accents-anudatta-svarita-and-double-svarita-in-devanaga).

How can I extend [this map](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/generic/devanagari) with the Unicode U+1CDA Vedic tone double svarita? I tried but did not succeed:

```
    ; TECkit mapping for ITRANS input scheme for writing Unicode IAST (0000-200D)
; by Abhinandan S.P. <abhinandan.sp@iiitb.net> and Shrisha Rao <shrao@acm.org>,
; based on harvardkyoto.map written by Daniel Stender.
;
; Updated 2014-09-01

LHSName "itrans-iast"
RHSName "Unicode"
LHSDescription "Devanagari-ITRANS input method for Unicode Roman (IAST)"
Version "2.00"

Define dot U+002E

Define a U+0061
Define A U+0041
Define i U+0069
Define I U+0049
Define u U+0075
Define U U+0055
Define R U+0052
Define L U+004C

Define e U+0065
Define E U+0045
Define o U+006F
Define H U+0048

Define k U+006B
Define h U+0068
Define g U+0067
Define G U+0047

Define c U+0063
Define C U+0043  
Define j U+006A
Define J U+004A

Define T U+0054
Define D U+0044
Define N U+004E

Define t U+0074
Define d U+0064
Define n U+006E

Define p U+0070
Define b U+0062
Define m U+006D

Define y U+0079
Define r U+0072
Define l U+006C
Define v U+0076
Define w U+0077

Define z U+007A
Define S U+0053
Define s U+0073
Define Y U+0059
Define O U+004F

Define anudatta U+002D  ; -
Define svarita U+0021   ; !
Define dsvar  U+003F 
Define tlde    U+007E
Define cret    U+005E   
Define M U+004D

Define q U+0071
Define f U+0066
Define x U+0078

Define zwj U+200D
Define zwn U+200C

Define anunasika U+0901
Define anusvara U+0C82
Define visarga  U+0C83

Define vstroke  U+0951
Define hstroke  U+0952
Define dstroke  U+1CDA


Define mdot     U+1E43
Define ndot     U+1E47
Define ntilde   U+00F1
Define tdot     U+1E6D
Define ddot     U+1E0D
Define ndota    U+1E45
Define sacute   U+015B
Define sdot     U+1E63
Define lbelow   U+1E3B
Define ldot     U+1E37

Define asvara   a
Define Asvara   U+0101
Define isvara   i
Define Isvara   U+012B
Define usvara   u
Define Usvara   U+016B
Define rvoc U+1E5B
Define Rvoc U+1E5D
Define lvoc U+1E37
Define Lvoc     U+1E38
Define Esvara   e
Define aisvara  a i
Define Osvara   o
Define ausvara  a u

Define ka   k
Define kha  k h
Define ga   g
Define gha  g h
Define Ga   ndota
Define cha  c
Define Cha  c h 
Define ja   j
Define jha  j h
Define Ja   ntilde
Define Ta   tdot
Define Tha  tdot h
Define Da   ddot
Define Dha  ddot h
Define Na   ndot
Define ta   t
Define tha  t h
Define da   d
Define dha  d h
Define na   n
Define pa   p
Define pha  p h
Define ba   b
Define bha  b h
Define ma   m
Define ya   y
Define ra   r
Define la   l
Define va   v
;Define wa       U+0CB5
Define sha  sacute
Define Sha  sdot
Define sa   s
Define ha   h

Define rla  ldot

Define danda    U+0964
Define ddanda   U+0965
;Define     U+0CCD
Define avagraha U+2019
Define lcb      U+007B
Define rcb      U+007D
Define zero     U+0CE6
Define cbindu   U+0901
Define ksha     ka Sha


pass(Unicode)

a > asvara
a a > Asvara
A > Asvara
i > isvara
i i > Isvara
I > Isvara
u > usvara
u u > Usvara
U > Usvara
R R i > rvoc
R cret i > rvoc
R R I > Rvoc
R cret I > Rvoc
L L i > lvoc
L cret i > lvoc
L L I > Lvoc
L cret I > Lvoc

e > Esvara

a i > aisvara
a M > a mdot
o > Osvara
o o > Osvara
O > Osvara
a u > ausvara
a dot N > a m cbindu
k > ka
k h > kha
k dot h > ka  
k x > ka ksha
k h dot h > kha 
k h x > kha ksha
g > ga
g dot h > ga 
g x > ga     ksha
g a dot n > ga anusvara
g h > gha
g h dot h > gha  
g h x > gha      ksha
tlde N  > Ga
N cret  > Ga
N tlde > Ga
G G > Ga
tlde N dot h > Ga  
N cret dot h > Ga  
tlde N x > Ga      ksha
N cret dot h > Ga  
;N cret x > zero    ksha
;N cret g > zero    ga
;N cret g h > zero    gha
n g > na ga
c > cha
c h > cha
c h h > Cha
;c h dot h > cha  
;c h x > Cha      ksha
;c h h x > Cha      ksha
C h > Cha
C h x > Cha  ksha
;C h dot h > Cha  
;c h h dot h > Cha  
j > ja 
j dot h > ja  
j x > ja      ksha
j h > jha
j h x > jha      ksha
j h dot h > jha  
tlde n > ntilde
tlde n a > Ja
tlde n x > Ja      ksha
tlde n dot h > Ja  
J N > Ja
J N x > Ja      ksha
T > Ta
T x > Ta      ksha
T dot h > Ta  
T h > Tha
T h dot h > Tha  
T h x > Tha      ksha
D > Da
D x > Da  ksha
D dot h > Da  
D h > Dha
D h dot h > Dha  
D h x > Dha      ksha
N > Na
N dot h > Na  
N x > Na  ksha
;N N > Na   Na
t > ta
t dot h > ta  
t x > ta      ksha
t h > tha
t h x > tha      ksha
t h dot h > tha  
d > da
d x > da      ksha
d dot h > da  
d h > dha
d h x > dha      ksha
d h dot h > dha  
n > na
n x > na      ksha
n dot h > na  
p > pa
p x > pa ksha
p dot h > pa  
p h x > pha ksha
p h dot h > pha  
b > ba
b x > ba ksha
b dot h > ba  
b h > bha
b h x > bha      ksha
b h dot h > bha  
m > ma
m dot h > ma  
m x > ma      ksha
y > ya
y dot h > ya  
y x > ya ksha
r > ra
r x > ra ksha
r dot h > ra  
l > la
l x > la      ksha
L > rla
L x > rla      ksha
l dot h > la  
L dot h > rla  
v > va
v x > va      ksha
v dot h > va  
w > va
w x > va      ksha
w dot h > va  
s h > sha
s h x > sha      ksha
s h dot h > sha  
s h h > Sha
s h h x > Sha      ksha
s h h dot h > Sha  
S h > Sha
S h x > Sha      ksha
S h dot h > Sha  
s > sa
s x > sa      ksha
s dot h > sa  
h > ha
h x > ha      ksha
h dot h > ha  
N cret x > zero ksha
x > ksha
x dot h > ksha  
k S h > ksha
k S h dot h > ksha  
G Y > ja Ja
j tlde n > ja   Ja
v a cret cret r > va ra  
m lcb rcb > ma  
lcb rcb > zwn
H > U+1E25
M > mdot
dot n > mdot
L > ldot

;dot m > anunasika


;U+004D > anusvara
;U+0029 M > U+0029 U+0CE6
;dot a M > avagraha zero
;dot n > anusvara
;U+0048 > visarga
dot a > avagraha
dot a lcb rcb > avagraha
;dot a N cret > avagraha U+0CE6

;U+002C >  
;dot N > na

svarita > vstroke
anudatta > hstroke
dsvar > dstroke


;U+002F dot > dot
;U+007C > danda
;U+007C U+007C > ddanda
;U+002D > U+002D
;U+005C dot > dot
;U+0022 > U+201D
;U+0027 > U+0027
;U+0028 > U+0028
;U+0029 > U+0029
;U+0060 > U+2018
;U+0060 U+0060 > U+201C

;U+0030 > U+0CE6    ; Numerals
;U+0031 > U+0CE7
;U+0032 > U+0CE8
;U+0033 > U+0CE9
;U+0034 > U+0CEA
;U+0035 > U+0CEB
;U+0036 > U+0CEC
;U+0037 > U+0CED
;U+0038 > U+0CEE
;U+0039 > U+0CEF

;pass(Unicode)

;UniClass [vyanjana] = (ka..dha pha..ba ra..la)
;UniClass [mvyanjana] = (pa ba bha)

;UniClass [svara] = (Asvara isvara Isvara usvara Usvara rvoc Rvoc lvoc Esvara aisvara Osvara ausvara)
;UniClass [matra] = (Amatra imatra Imatra umatra Umatra rmatra Rmatra lmatra Ematra aimatra Omatra aumatra)
;UniClass [naletter] = (na)
;UniClass [anusvaraletter] = (zero)
;UniClass [avaletter] = (avagraha)
;UniClass [maletter] = (ma)
;UniClass [Naletter] = (Na)
;UniClass [galetter] = (Ga)
;UniClass [jaletter] = (Ja)
;UniClass [osvaraletter] = (Osvara)
;UniClass [omatra] = (Omatra)

;UniClass [vletter] = ( )

;[naletter] [vyanjana] > [anusvaraletter] [vyanjana]
;[maletter] [mvyanjana] > [anusvaraletter] [mvyanjana]
;[maletter] [maletter] [osvaraletter] > [anusvaraletter] [maletter] [omatra]
;[galetter] [vyanjana] > [anusvaraletter] [vyanjana]
;[jaletter] [vyanjana] > [anusvaraletter] [vyanjana]
;[Naletter] [vyanjana] > [anusvaraletter] [vyanjana]
;[anusvaraletter] [vyanjana] [svara] > [anusvaraletter] [vyanjana][matra]

;pass(Unicode)

;UniClass [vyanjana] = (ka .. ha rla)
;UniClass [svara] = (Asvara isvara Isvara usvara Usvara rvoc Rvoc lvoc Esvara aisvara Osvara ausvara)
;UniClass [matra] = (Amatra imatra Imatra umatra Umatra rmatra Rmatra lmatra Ematra aimatra Omatra aumatra)
;[vyanjana] [svara] > [vyanjana] [matra]


;pass(Unicode)

;UniClass [vyanjana] = (ka .. ha)
;[vyanjana]=v1 [vyanjana]=v2 > @v1   @v2

;pass(Unicode)

;UniClass [vyanjana] = (ka .. ha)
;[vyanjana]=v1 [vyanjana]=v2 > @v1   @v2
 ;pass(Unicode)
;Uniclass [vyanjana] = (ka .. ha rla)
;[vyanjana] asvara > [vyanjana]
```

These were my addings:

```
Define dsvar  U+003F 
Define dstroke  U+1CDA
dsvar > dstroke
```

And this the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newfontfamily\textskt{Sanskrit2003}
\newfontfamily\textiast[Mapping=itrans-iast]{Sanskrit2003}

\newcommand\devtext{
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=itrans-dvn]{Sanskrit2003}}

\newcommand\iast{
           \fontspec[Script=Greek,Mapping=itrans-iast]{Sanskrit2003}}    


 \newcommand{\Paragraph}[1]{\devtext{#1}
\par\medskip
{\iast{#1}}}





\begin{document}

\Paragraph{nama!ste rudra ma-nyava! u-tota- iSha!ve- namaH. \\
 nama!ste astu- dhanva!ne bA-hubhyA!mu-ta te- nama!H}


\end{document}
```

And in the existing map there is no ligature existing between svarita, anudatta and visarga. After rendering it looks like this नम॑◌ः

I would be very happy for any suggestions how to extend that file.

Comment: unrelated to the mapping question but your catode changes for `~` and `^` will have no effect in `\Paragraph` you will get a missing math mode error if you use `^` in that argument.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I just **deleted** them in the code

Comment: Note that Sanskrit2003 font does not have the `dev2` font feature, handles the font shaping better for these accents.

Comment: You have defined `dsvar` as `?`, yet it is not used in the code, as far as I can see.

Comment: You need the reverse of dev-to-iast (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502515/reversing-text-mapping-devanagari-to-iast-transliteration?noredirect=1#comment1321060_502515), with vedic accents added. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you Cicada! That's how I definded dsvar: `Define dsvar  U+003F ; ?. 
Define dstroke  U+1CDA;  ᳚ and
dsvar > dstroke

Comment: In mapping files, `;` is the comment character, just like `%` is the comment character in tex files. In your mapping file, is there a reason most of it is commented out? The way it is set up, it requires multiple Unicode passes to resolve all the mappings and classes of mappings, yet most of them are commented out. Is it intended to be a test map file for double svarita only?

Comment: That is a good question I asked myself also. I found that mapping file in following directory: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping. I never changed it. I installed that file 2.5 years ago when I installed TEX.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the mapping programming being used; I use a much simpler method:

```
 U+0076 U+0074 U+0064 U+0073 <>  U+1CDA; ᳚ vtds
 U+0076 U+0074 U+0075 <>  U+0951; ॑ vtu
```

etc

to get

[image: double]

Note that if you put `?` in your code, you get the `᳚`.

I will do a mapping file, over the next couple of days, if all goes well.

---

**Edit 2: Fonts with Vedic extensions**

`Sanskrit 2003` does not have Vedic extensions:

[image: Sanskrit 2003]

(the keyboard shortcuts are just my (temp) naming convention)

`Sanskrit Text` has Vedic extensions:

[image: Sanskrit Text]

(missing acute and grave accents)

`Noto Serif Devanagari` has them, except the last two (ring, and double ring):

[image: Noto Serif Devanagari]

And `Shobhika`: note the well-adjusted placement of the double svarita:

[image: Shobhika]

I have no other fonts with Vedic.

So, yes, fonts could be an issue.
(The simple marks can be composed by hand, though.)

---

**Edit 3: Testing the fonts**

In the meantime, to test the fonts on your system and see whether they have the Vedic extensions, compile the following minimal map file as `iast_test`:

```
;Test map

LHSName "iast_test"
RHSName "Unicode"
LHSDescription "test input method for Vedic extensions"
Version "0.00"


pass(Unicode)

 U+0028 U+0068 U+0068 U+0029 <>  U+0903; ः (hh)
 U+0028 U+002C U+002C U+0029 <>  U+0951; ॑ (,,)
 U+0028 U+002E U+002E U+0029 <>  U+0952; ॒ (..)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0063 U+0029 <>  U+0953; ॓ (ac)
 U+0028 U+0067 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+0954; ॔ (gr)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0062 U+0069 U+0029 <>  U+0900; ऀ (cbi)
 U+0028 U+006D U+0068 U+0029 <>  U+0902; ं (mh)
 U+0074 U+0061 <>  U+0924; त ta
 U+006E U+0061 <>  U+0928; न na
 U+006D U+0061 <>  U+092E; म ma
 U+0073 U+0061 <>  U+0938; स sa
 U+0074 U+002D <>  U+0924 U+094D; त् t-
 U+006E U+002D <>  U+0928 U+094D; न् n-
 U+006D U+002D <>  U+092E U+094D; म् m-
 U+0073 U+002D <>  U+0938 U+094D; स् s-
 U+006D U+0061 U+0061 <>  U+092E U+093E; मा maa
 U+0074 U+0065 <>  U+0924 U+0947; ते te
 U+0028 U+006B U+0029 <>  U+1CD0; ᳐ (k)
 U+0028 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD1; ᳑ (s)
 U+0028 U+0070 U+0029 <>  U+1CD2; ᳒ (p)
 U+0028 U+006E U+0029 <>  U+1CD3; ᳓ (n)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006D U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD4; ᳔ (yms)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+0061 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD5; ᳕ (yais)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD6; ᳖ (yis)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD7; ᳗ (ykis)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CD8; ᳘ (cb)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD9; ᳙ (ykiss)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CDA; ᳚ (ds)
 U+0028 U+0074 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CDB; ᳛ (ts)
 U+0028 U+006B U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CDC; ᳜ (ka)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDD; ᳝ (db)
 U+0028 U+0032 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDE; ᳞ (2db)
 U+0028 U+0033 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDF; ᳟ (3db)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE0; ᳠ (rkis)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE1; ᳡ (ais)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE2; ᳢ (vs)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CE3; ᳣ (vu)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0076 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CE4; ᳤ (rvu)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE5; ᳥ (va)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0076 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE6; ᳦ (rva)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0075 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CE7; ᳧ (vut)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0061 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CE8; ᳨ (vat)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE9; ᳩ (aa)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CEA; ᳪ (ab)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0076 U+0029 <>  U+1CEB; ᳫ (av)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0076 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CEC; ᳬ (avt)
 U+0028 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CED; ᳭ (t)
 U+0028 U+0068 U+006C U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CEE; ᳮ (hla)
 U+0028 U+006C U+006E U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CEF; ᳯ (lna)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+006C U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CF0; ᳰ (rla)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0075 U+006D U+0029 <>  U+1CF1; ᳱ (aum)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+1CF2; ᳲ (ar)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0061 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+1CF3; ᳳ (rar)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0029 <>  U+1CF4; ᳴ (c)
 U+0028 U+006A U+0029 <>  U+1CF5; ᳵ (j)
 U+0028 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CF6; ᳶ (u)
 U+0028 U+0078 U+0078 U+0078 U+0029 <>  U+1CF7; ᳷ (xxx)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0061 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CF8; ᳸ (rab)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0072 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CF9; ᳹ (dra)
```

The input method is `(`*tone abbreviation*`)`, e.g. `(ds)`.

Use the following tex file to test if the font has the required Vedic glyphs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}

\newcommand\fsname{Sanskrit Text}%<=== name of font to test

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\feng{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.62]%for Latin text

\newfontfamily\fsnsk[Mapping=iast_test,Script=Devanagari]{\fsname}[Colour=blue]%mapped font

%macros to test symbol input method
\newcommand\fsktna{न}
\newcommand\fsktma{^^^^092e}
\newcommand\fskthalant{^^^^094d}
\newcommand\fsktsa{स}
\newcommand\fsktta{त}
\newcommand\fskte{^^^^0947}
\newcommand\fsktA{ा}
\newcommand\udatta{^^^^0951}
\newcommand\doublesvarita{^^^^1cda}

\begin{document}


\fsnsk {\feng \fsname\ font:}

नमा॑स्ते᳚ {\feng (direct input)}

\fsktna\fsktma\fsktA\udatta\fsktsa\fskthalant\fsktta\fskte\doublesvarita   \ {\feng (macro/symbol input)}

namaa(,,)s-te(ds) {\feng (mapped input)}

{\feng (hh)}~ma(hh)
{\feng (,,)}~ma(,,)
{\feng (..)}~ma(..)
{\feng (ac)}~ma(ac)
{\feng (gr)}~ma(gr)
{\feng (cbi)}~ma(cbi)
{\feng (mh)}~ma(mh)

{\feng (k)}~ma(k)
{\feng (s)}~ma(s)
{\feng (p)}~ma(p)
{\feng (n)}~ma(n)
{\feng (yms)}~ma(yms)
{\feng (yais)}~ma(yais)
{\feng (yis)}~ma(yis)
{\feng (ykis)}~ma(ykis)
{\feng (cb)}~ma(cb)
{\feng (ykiss)}~ma(ykiss)
{\feng (ds)}~ma(ds)
{\feng (ts)}~ma(ts)
{\feng (ka)}~ma(ka)
{\feng (db)}~ma(db)
{\feng (2db)}~ma(2db)
{\feng (3db)}~ma(3db)
{\feng (rkis)}~ma(rkis)
{\feng (ais)}~ma(ais)
{\feng (vs)}~ma(vs)
{\feng (vu)}~ma(vu)
{\feng (rvu)}~ma(rvu)
{\feng (va)}~ma(va)
{\feng (rva)}~ma(rva)
{\feng (vut)}~ma(vut)
{\feng (vat)}~ma(vat)
{\feng (aa)}~ma(aa)
{\feng (ab)}~ma(ab)
{\feng (av)}~ma(av)
{\feng (avt)}~ma(avt)
{\feng (t)}~ma(t)
{\feng (hla)}~ma(hla)
{\feng (lna)}~ma(lna)
{\feng (rla)}~ma(rla)
{\feng (aum)}~ma(aum)
{\feng (ar)}~ma(ar)
{\feng (rar)}~ma(rar)
{\feng (c)}~ma(c)
{\feng (j)}~ma(j)
{\feng (u)}~ma(u)
%{\feng (xxx)}~ma(xxx)
{\feng (rab)}~ma(rab)
{\feng (dra)}~ma(dra)

\end{document}
```

Change `\fsname` to the name of the font you want to test.

Output format is:

[image: Vedic glyphs test output]

---

**Edit 4: Findings so far**

(a) `Shobhika` is definitely a very useful font to have. It is designed by the IITB and has a SIL licence and the page on CTAN ([here](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.315.1553423491.4318.ctan-ann@ctan.org?lang=en)) links to [github](https://github.com/Sandhi-IITBombay/Shobhika/releases) for the latest version.

`Shobhika`s Vedic coverage is as follows (note: tones and signs are carried over "as-is" into the transliteration mapping, on the basis that they are equivalent to a musical/prosody notation system):

[image: Shobhika Vedic]

The signs are independent characters, and the tones are diacritics - both are attached to म just for illustration purposes only.

(b) 
Discussion seems to use a IAST-like method, abhiśrī́ḥ (as [here](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/eieol/vedol/10)), but sometimes the accented characters are one glyph, and sometimes they are base character + combining diacritic. That makes a mapping file slightly more complex/longer, but still quite achievable.

Using iast-to-deva mapping for reconstructing the Devanagari from the transliteration from the UTexas page:

[image: IAST to deva]

(c)
For convenience, being able to use a "plain" keyboard to enter input sounds useful. Several mapping files, mapping in different directions, result:

[image: maps]

For the "plain" maps, to make the input as readable as possible, long vowels and consonants are doubled, `-` is halant, and Vedic tones and signs are enclosed in `()` to make them visibly distinct from the text.

(d)
Next step is explore the `.org` site; perhaps open a github account or similar to store all the files; and find out, besides the double svarita, what the other 40 tones and signs mean, and their usage. (It is also possible that the IITB might have other resources etc available.)

---

**Edit 5: map code for Vedic**

Put this in your `trans` .map file, compile it into the .tec file, and type in your latex code, example `(ud)` to get udatta. Double svarita is `(ds)`, triple svarita is `(ts)`, and so on.

```
; accents
 U+0028 U+0068 U+0068 U+0029 <>  U+0903; ः (hh)
 U+0028 U+0075 U+0064 U+0029 <>  U+0951; ॑ (ud)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+006E U+0029 <>  U+0952; ॒ (an)
 U+0028 U+0067 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+0953; ॓ (gr)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0063 U+0029 <>  U+0954; ॔ (ac)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0062 U+0069 U+0029 <>  U+0900; ऀ (cbi)
 U+0028 U+006D U+0068 U+0029 <>  U+0902; ं (mh)



; Vedic extension: tones and signs (41 glyphs)

 U+0028 U+006B U+0029 <>  U+1CD0; ᳐ (k)
 U+0028 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD1; ᳑ (s)
 U+0028 U+0070 U+0029 <>  U+1CD2; ᳒ (p)
 U+0028 U+006E U+0029 <>  U+1CD3; ᳓ (n)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006D U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD4; ᳔ (yms)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+0061 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD5; ᳕ (yais)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD6; ᳖ (yis)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD7; ᳗ (ykis)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CD8; ᳘ (cb)
 U+0028 U+0079 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CD9; ᳙ (ykiss)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CDA; ᳚ (ds)
 U+0028 U+0074 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CDB; ᳛ (ts)
 U+0028 U+006B U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CDC; ᳜ (ka)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDD; ᳝ (db)
 U+0028 U+0032 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDE; ᳞ (2db)
 U+0028 U+0033 U+0064 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CDF; ᳟ (3db)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+006B U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE0; ᳠ (rkis)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0069 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE1; ᳡ (ais)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0073 U+0029 <>  U+1CE2; ᳢ (vs)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CE3; ᳣ (vu)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0076 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CE4; ᳤ (rvu)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE5; ᳥ (va)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0076 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE6; ᳦ (rva)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0075 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CE7; ᳧ (vut)
 U+0028 U+0076 U+0061 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CE8; ᳨ (vat)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CE9; ᳩ (aa)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CEA; ᳪ (ab)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0076 U+0029 <>  U+1CEB; ᳫ (av)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0076 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CEC; ᳬ (avt)
 U+0028 U+0074 U+0029 <>  U+1CED; ᳭ (t)
 U+0028 U+0068 U+006C U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CEE; ᳮ (hla)
 U+0028 U+006C U+006E U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CEF; ᳯ (lna)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+006C U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CF0; ᳰ (rla)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0075 U+006D U+0029 <>  U+1CF1; ᳱ (aum)
 U+0028 U+0061 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+1CF2; ᳲ (ar)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0061 U+0072 U+0029 <>  U+1CF3; ᳳ (rar)
 U+0028 U+0063 U+0029 <>  U+1CF4; ᳴ (c)
 U+0028 U+006A U+0029 <>  U+1CF5; ᳵ (j)
 U+0028 U+0075 U+0029 <>  U+1CF6; ᳶ (u)
 U+0028 U+0072 U+0061 U+0062 U+0029 <>  U+1CF8; ᳸ (rab)
 U+0028 U+0064 U+0072 U+0061 U+0029 <>  U+1CF9; ᳹ (dra)
```

The tones and signs look like this in Unicode display map:

[image: Vedic]

and udatta/svarita is here in the middle of devanagari letters and numbers:

[image: udatta]

Comment: Great Cicada, thanks for that fast reply! I know, your time is costly. So I appreciate this a lot. I use linux so maybe not all fonts will fit also for that? I was also thinking about which maps the users of https://sanskritdocuments.org/ handle. I couldn't find an exact instruction...

Comment: @Denis Various mappings can done for different purposes. There may not necessarily be official maps defined - since there are three or four commonly used schemes around.

Comment: Thank you very much for your endeavors. I'll be back home tonight and will test it. I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: Hm, there comes an error message: File: iast_text.tex; Type: Error. Line 8. LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: My line 8: **\newfontfamily\fsnsk[Mapping=iast_test.map,Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}[Colour=blue]**

Comment: I created a new folder and created there the iast_text.map and compiled to .tec file. the beautiful made Shobhika font I installed with "getnonfreefonts" in TeX.

Comment: Edit 5: the Vedic map. Shall I insert it into the iast_test.map or create a new trans.file?

Comment: @Denis Good to hear about the outcome. Agree that Shobhika is very well made (check the IITB site every now and then, as bug fixes and enhancements are made from time to time). For the Vedic map, place it where most convenient to you (even in both places, as you please).

Comment: As I told you, there is still an error occuring: iast_test.tex; Error line 9; Missing\begin{document}. Am not able to find the cause...

Comment: @Denis A missing or extra brace can cause that, as well as other things. Post a separate question with the details and the actual code.

Comment: Here is the new thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522792/troubleshooting-for-compilation-error

Comment: Thanks to ShreevatsaR we could solve the problem. I really like these fonts.