# Trouble getting vedic accents working with xetex

Tags: xetex

I have referred to [Cicada's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380369/how-to-create-vedic-accents-anudatta-svarita-and-double-svarita-in-devanaga/522655) to get vedic swara markings working on my osx. To test my MWE on your system, you will have to install fonts [Shobhika](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/shobhika.zip) and [Sanskrit 2003](https://www.oah.in/Sanskrit/sanskrit2003.zip) - sorry about that!

The MWE I used is the same as what Cicada posted:

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\mysktfont{Shobhika Regular}
\newfontface\fplain{\mysktfont}% no mapping
\newcommand\devtext{
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=itrans-dvn2]{\mysktfont}}%mapping transliteration to Devanagari
\newcommand\iast{
           \fontspec[Mapping=itrans-iast2]{\mysktfont}} %mapping transliteration to IAST transliteration scheme

 \newcommand{\Paragraph}[1]{\devtext{#1}
\par\medskip
{\iast{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\fplain
नम॑ः 

\Paragraph{
nama!ste^^^^1cda rudra ma-nyava! u-tota- iSha!ve- namaH. \\
 nama!ste^^^^1cda astu- dhanva!ne bA-hubhyA!mu-ta te- nama!H
}

\end{document}
```

I prepared my system thus:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Shreeshrii/xetex-itrans.git
$ cp itrans-iast.map itrans-iast2.map
$ # Edit itrans-iast2.map
$ Teckit_compile itrans-iast2
$ diff -du itrans-iast.map itrans-iast2.map 
--- itrans-iast.map 2020-02-02 05:58:51.000000000 -0800
+++ itrans-iast2.map    2020-02-02 06:00:15.000000000 -0800
@@ -153,6 +153,9 @@

 pass(Unicode)

+svarita > U+0951
+anudatta > U+0952
+
 a > asvara
 a a > Asvara
 A > Asvara


$ cp *.tec *.map /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/xetex-itrans/
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory

$ sudo mkdir -p !$ 

$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/xetex-itrans/ 
Password:

$ sudo cp *.tec *.map /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/xetex-itrans/


$ sudo mktexlsr 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

The pdf file resulting from running `xelatex swara.tex` shows that the itrans text is not converted to devanagari:

[image: image of swara.pdf]

I found a few errors in the log file (`swara.log`) generated from `xelatex`. The entire log file is uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uine7jaips7dxis/swara-shobhika.log?dl=0)

```
.................................................
Font mapping `itrans-dvn2.tec' for font `Shobhika Regular' not found.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Shobhika Regular/I (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'ShobhikaRegular(2)' created for font 'Shobhika Regular' with
. options [Mapping=itrans-iast2].
. 
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Shobhika
. Regular/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=itrans-iast2;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Shobhika Regular/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=itrans-iast2;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with
. NFSS spec.: <->"Shobhika
. Regular/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=itrans-iast2;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
```

I verified that the `Shobhika` font is indeed installed on my mac by running `xetex opentype-info.tex` after setting `myfontname` to `Shobhika Regular`:

[image: Output of xetex opentype-info.tex for Shobhika font]

The font features directive in the fontspec in my source (`swara.tex`) refers to `Mapping=itrans-dvn2` but I don't find any map or tec files named `itrans-dvn2*` under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/xetex-itrans/` This is one of the errors in the log file. @Cicada never said anything about generating this file and I don't see it in the git repo either.

I changed the font name from `Shobhika` to `Sanskrit 2003` in my source and that failed too. Entire log is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xg8c8vc1atn387/swara-sanksrit2003.log?dl=0)

### Update 1

Without relying on the `.tec` files to provide swara markings, I inserted the them manually into my document (as was suggested in another post):

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\mysktfont{Shobhika Regular}
\newfontface\fplain{\mysktfont}% no mapping
\newcommand\devtext{
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=itrans-dvn]{\mysktfont}}%mapping transliteration to Devanagari
\newcommand\iast{
           \fontspec[Mapping=itrans-iast]{\mysktfont}} %mapping transliteration to IAST transliteration scheme

\newcommand\svarita{^^^^0951}
\newcommand\anudatta{^^^^0952}
\newcommand\doublesvarita{^^^^1cda}

 \newcommand{\Paragraph}[1]{\devtext{#1}
\par\medskip
{\iast{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\fplain
नम॑ः 

\Paragraph{nama\svarita ste\doublesvarita\ rudra ma\anudatta nyava\svarita\ u\anudatta tota\anudatta\ iSha\svarita ve\anudatta\ namaH. \\
 nama\svarita ste\doublesvarita\ astu\anudatta\ dhanva\svarita ne bA\anudatta hubhyA\svarita mu\anudatta ta te\anudatta\ nama\svarita H}

\end{document}
```

This gives me text with swara markings, with one exception that I have pointed out with a red arrow:

[image: Image with macros for swara markings]

If there's a way to get rid of the weird circle between `नम` and `ः`, my problem would be resolved.

### Update 2

Output with font `Siddhanta`

[image: Output with font Siddhanta]

Comment: Update: I changed `Mapping=itrans-dvn2` to `Mapping=itrans-dvn` and used the macros for `anudatta` etc. and can now see swara markings in my document. There is a weird character between the svarita marking and `H` in ` nama{\svarita}H`. How can it be fixed?

Comment: `itrans-iast2` is distribution file `itrans-iast` with two lines added: `svarita > U+0951
anudatta > U+0952` and `itrans-dvn2` is distribution file `iast-dvn` with the equivalent: `svarita > vstroke
anudatta > hstroke` if I recall correctly. `\svarita` with a \ is a macro - a mapped font converts the input characters into the output characters according to the conversion rules specified in the mapping file. Macro names are not part of that process. Just like you type the characters `na` (not `\na`) and they are mapped to `न`.

Comment: What code did you run? `\svarita` macro is not defined in the MWE posted above, so it gives the error `! Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: How do I generate `itrans-dvn2`? Since your reply to the other post said nothing
about generating it, I continued to use itrans-dvn. Links to my source and logfile:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7xlkr0f1a3q8p7/new-swara.tex?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4sxx35heds2e7i/new-swara.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @ShreevatsaR 's answer in the linked question explains how to compile a `.map` file into a `.tec` file. What to edit in the map files is described in prior comment. It's the same edit in both, in fact. If you want to add double svarita, similar syntax. The map files are converted into regex, as I understand. I recommend @ShreevatsaR 's advice to edit your own, or use direct input. The shipped iast ones are unworkable as they are for Vedic as you can see from the linked question.

Comment: Post your code and log here instead of linking. Links rot and break over time, making the question useless for others.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522409/extending-map-file-with-u1cda-vedic-tone-double-svarita?noredirect=1&lq=1 help?

Comment: In your dropbox link for new-svara.tex, the three macros `\newcommand\svarita{^^^^0951}
\newcommand\anudatta{^^^^0952}
\newcommand\doublesvarita{^^^^1cda}` illustrate how the `itrans` mapping file cannot handle some combinations in the devanagari: compare the mapped output (नम॑ः displays wrong in my browser also) with the unmapped one (that uses the `\fplain` font and produces the correct shape). The macros do not rely on mapping, in any case; so you can use them in place of direct input if you do not have a Vedic IME. Similarly with all the other accents.

Comment: @Cicada thanks a lot for your input so far. I will go through the other post and also update  my question tomorrow.

Comment: If you have Sanskrit 2003 why don't you install Siddhanta from the same place I installed Sanskrit2003: http://www.sanskritweb.net/itrans/index.html#SIDDHANTA this font is much better set up and námaḥ should work out of the box with it

Comment: @Au101 I merely replaced the font name from `Shobhika Regular` to `Siddhanta` in the example I posted in Update 1. The weirdness with visarga after swarita marking still exists. Please check the question for Update 2 that shows the output with Siddhanta.

Comment: Has anyone had luck with directly inputting devanagari text along with swara markings from the keyboard and have xelatex generate the pdf? I'm hoping this will be an easier route to pursue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no knowledge of devanagari but it looks as if the input order of the stress sign UDATTA (U+0951) and VISARGA (U+0903) matters. 
There is a discussion here about the input order: https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/2017

It also looks as if the noto fonts has small problems and that siddhanta is better. (https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1551).

When I compile the following in a current texlive with lualatex-dev (and so with harfbuzz enabled) (the ^^^^-notation is only there as it is easier for me to input)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotosansDevanagari}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari]

\setsansfont{siddhanta}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}
^^^^0928^^^^092e^^^^0951^^^^0903 नम॑ः

^^^^0928^^^^092e^^^^0903^^^^0951 नमः॑

\sffamily

^^^^0928^^^^092e^^^^0951^^^^0903 नम॑ः

^^^^0928^^^^092e^^^^0903^^^^0951 नमः॑

\end{document}
```

I get this output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Ulrike!  Can you explain the benefits, if any,  of using `lualatex/lualatex-dev` over `xelatex`?

Comment: luatex has better microtype and bidi features and you can use the lua callbacks. And now that harfbuzz has been integrated (in the luahbtex engine used by lualatex-dev) the main advantage of xetex is gone. Beside this the maintainer of luaotfload are nice people ;-).

Comment: side remark: In case you are considering it: don't assign the bounty directly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not assigning the bounty directly.